# Wi-Fi disconnects when I lock the mac

Tags: wifi

Everytime I lock my mac and log back in two minutes, It has disconnected the wi-fi network. Is there a setting to disable this?

Model: Mac Book Pro - 15-inch, Mid 2010
I lock it by clicking 'Login Window...' after clicking my username on top right corner of the menu bar.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Do the following:

Find out what the network interface is for your wifi. Mine is "en1" for this example (I have obfuscated my MAC addresses with "00")

```
ifconfig
en1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500  
ether 00:00:00:00:00:00  
inet6 0000::000:0000:0000:0000%en1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x5
inet 10.0.1.16 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 10.0.1.255
media: autoselect
status: active
```

Then, you need to set up the airport util for your wireless card to tell it not to shut off:

```
cd /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources
sudo ./airport en1 prefs DisconnectOnLogout=NO
```

Comment: I really don't know why this isn't the accepted answer, this was exactly the problem I was having. Thanks!

Comment: Yep. This works! :-)

Comment: This didn't work on my 2013 MBPr, unfortunately.

Comment: Worked - this should be correct answer.

Comment: Didn't work on late 2013 MBPr.

Comment: Didnt work for me neither, seems there is a difference between choosing "show login window" and "lock screen" that you cannot get around. See Sul's answer about keychain prefs.

Comment: Did not work on 2013 MBA.

Comment: what if it's not a wireless card? (ethernet via thunderbolt). What would be the path?

Comment: This worked for me ... as long as I remember to lock my screen by hitting "command alt power" and NOT "command control power" :)

Comment: (for followers, command control power is "reboot" so don't do that. If you don't have an eject button, "lock screen" shortcut is `ctrl+shift+power`)

Comment: Unfortunately this wasn't enough for me (encryption type "WPA2 Enterprise" however at home using Wifi "WPA2 Personal" it stays connected just fine). FWIW

Comment: Does not work for me on a 2015 MBP running 10.11 and locking via command option power.

Comment: Just trying this on MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015). I'm wondering if the reason it hasn't worked for some others is that for me, at least,the Wifi adapter is en0, not en1.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on 2012 MBP running Sierra.

Comment: If you're unsure which is your Wifi connection, you can look in System Preferences > Network. You can either compare the assigned IP address or the MAC address (physical network address of the card) to the entries in the ifconfig output.

Comment: Unfortunately, this has stopped working already for me. It did work immediately after testing, but at some point it stopped working again (might have worked only once, even).

Comment: Does not work on 2017 MacBook Pro running High Sierra 10.13.2.

Answer (score 20):

---

**EDIT**: Please see John's answer above, which basically says to open Terminal and run:

```
cd /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources
sudo ./airport en1 prefs DisconnectOnLogout=NO
```

where `en1` is the name of your Mac's WiFi interface. You can get it with this Terminal command:

```
ifconfig | grep -B 6 'status: active' | head -n 1 | cut -d : -f 1
```

when WiFi is the only active interface (that is, no Ethernet cable attached).

To list the interface settings, run in Terminal:

```
./airport en1 prefs
```

Typical output is:

```
AirPort preferences for en1:

DisconnectOnLogout=NO
Unable to retrieve JoinMode
JoinModeFallback=DoNothing
RememberRecentNetworks=YES
RequireAdminIBSS=NO
RequireAdminNetworkChange=NO
RequireAdminPowerToggle=NO
WoWEnabled=YES
```

---

Other people's Macs are misbehaving in a similar way, read for example [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4165119?start=0&tstart=0) and [this](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1410516&page=3). Although I own a similar MacBook Pro that runs 10.8.2 I can count myself fortunate not to suffer this issue.

Consequently the list below is rather a compilation of possible fixes (some may even seem absurd or just plain obvious) than tested recommendations:

- Lock the screen differently, for instance with a 3rd party program (http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/2000041, applies to Mac OS X 10.7.5) (I use [hot corners](http://heresthethingblog.com/2012/02/06/mac-tip-control-desktop-hot-corners/) for that).
- Some claim that Apple WiFi equipment spares them from suffering this issue (maybe because an old, possibly incompatible base station was replaced?)  (http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=15380401&postcount=57 and http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=15442704&postcount=63).
- Add a new network location (http://osxdaily.com/2012/08/02/fix-os-x-mountain-lion-wireless-connection-problems/).
- Change MTU size to prevent dropped connections (also http://osxdaily.com/2012/08/02/fix-os-x-mountain-lion-wireless-connection-problems/).

  (These two don't relate exactly to disconnects after locking but more generally to connectivity problems in "Mountain Lion".)
- As a last resort, a clean install (restoring applications/settings from Time Machine) might help.

I checked the power management settings (command `pmset`) and `defaults` but couldn't find anything.

(My setup is: clean "Mountain Lion" install (with restore from Time Machine) and Airport Express base station.)

Hope this will help...

Comment: One comment, most third party programs only lock the main screen - if you have a second monitor, or someone can attach one, they're useless.

Comment: Changing the preferences via `airport` in the terminal did not resolve this issue for my High Sierra 10.13.2 MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 6):

Try the workaround here: http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/2000041

> The problem with OS X is to "lock" your screen you have two options, either let the screen saver time out and lock your screen (which doesn't disconnect WIFI) or clicking on your "user name" on the top right corner and choosing "Login Window" which essentially locks your mac and takes you to a login window, however this approach disconnects the WIFI Connection.
>
> The work around I have found is installing an app called "Lock Me Now" from the app store and once it has been installed launch it and from the preferences "check" "Just Lock" under "Lock Type" which does the same thing as the screen saver timing out. Also for ease of use you can assign a keyboard shortcut to simplify the process of locking your Mac (I chose to use Command + L )

Comment: I realized that my initial problem was actually resolved by this, but the workaround I had built worked better with @John's answer. I'm going back to yours, though, as it makes it easier to lock my desktop and walk away without worrying about everything turning off while I'm gone. : ) Thanks!

Comment: The problem is, this is a security risk, as it displays your username publicly when you wake it, even if you have your login window set not to.

Answer (score 3):

You can live without "lock me now" app.

just use:

**CONTROL + SHIFT + 'key to eject cd'** (or if you don't have an eject key, `control+shift+power`)

Comment: what do you mean by "lock me now"?

Comment: Pretty sure he means the above mentioned program in the app store.  His suggestion does the same thing without having to have an app.

Comment: Unfortunately this method also drops the network on MBPr's

Comment: @gWaldo, Really? High Sierra?

Comment: @Pacerier No, whatever was current in 2014... When I posted that comment.

Answer (score 3):

Open `Applications > Utilities > Keychain Access` then go to *Keychain Access* in the menu bar on the top, then *Preferences* - click "*show keychain status in the menu bar*".

You will see a little lock on the menu bar ... click on it then lock screen from there.

Comment: I use this all the time, and I still get disconnected from my network.

Comment: This preference option is not present on my MacBook Pro running High Sierra 10.13.12.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by writing simple service for Mac, this is best solution for this problem.

Try this out -http://tecride.blogspot.in/2015/04/wifi-disconnects-when-you-lock-osx.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This is the only answer that actually works without requiring the user to completely change his/her workflow.

Comment: This is the best answer for me (2015 MBP, OS 10.11), though I'm disappointed that I need to learn a new lock shortcut.

Comment: As I commented above, this will show your username to anyone trying to unlock your Mac, even if you have your login window set not to. That's a security risk.

Comment: the article is no longer available, that's why it would have been better to paste the solution directly here

Answer (score 0):

For OS X 10.9, instead of locking your Mac consider using the following command in terminal:

```
open -a /System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Versions/A/Resources/ScreenSaverEngine.app
```

The command starts the `ScreenSaveEngine.app` which locks the screen without disconnecting the Wi-Fi. I am not sure if it works on other versions of OS X.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution for dummies like me

###### To find your WiFi interface you can open up a terminal and run this following command. In `macOS Big Sur` WiFi interface it is named `en0`

```bsh
➜  ~ ifconfig
```

###### Now move into `airport` utility folder

```bsh
➜  ~ cd /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/
```

###### List the preferences for WiFi interface. In my case `en0`

```bsh
➜  ~ ./airport en0 prefs
```

###### Finally to do not let WiFi disconnecting on logout, change the related preference to `NO`

```bsh
➜  ~ ./airport en0 prefs DisconnectOnLogout=NO
```

Answer (score -2):

For maverick users-

To enabled the "Open Wireless Diagnostics.." as it doesn't show up by default to diagnose the WIFI connection.

Click the wifi icon on the menu bar with the Option key pressed. On the bottom of the list, you have "Open Wireless Diagnostics..."

Answer (score -2):

found a solution for this problem. Seems pretty well documented

http://osxdaily.com/2014/04/24/fix-mac-disconnect-wifi-sleep/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Links tend to die over time. If [when] that happens your answer will not be very helpful. Please provide the salient points from the link in your answer. Also, how does your answer differ from the nine answers already posted, including the accepted answer?

Comment: In accepted answer, 

1. many comments are there and they told - 'Didn't work on late 2013 MBPr.', So, I didn't try accepted answer

2. I was searching a GUI solution not CLI solution

So, this is different solution from another one

Comment: yes, I know stackoverflow rules but in this link, they showed via images and it was difficult to write everything in words. So, I shared link only.