# Why does my VPN client (Viscosity) disconnect when I lock my screen?

Tags: wifi, vpn, screen-lock

Using[this information](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71884/wi-fi-disconnects-when-i-lock-the-mac?newreg=0070fa62f2724843b00f969eedc8167d), I've set it so that the WiFi doesn't disconnect when I lock my mac. To lock the mac, I'm using this alias to lock my screen from the command line: `alias lockscreen='/System/Library/CoreServices/"Menu Extras"/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend'` obtained from [this article](http://osxdaily.com/2012/03/30/lock-mac-desktop-command-line/).

Unfortunately, when I lock my screen and come back, the WiFi stays connected but Viscosity, the VPN client I use, doesn't. I went to [this website](https://www.sparklabs.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2067) and it gave me the advice to keep my network adapter always on and linked to the same StackOverflow link I linked at the top. Is there a way I can keep Viscosity connected? I'm open to other VPN clients as well, I just need a good one that stays connected when I lock the screen and the wireless is connected.

I'm running Viscosity version 1.7 and my Mac information is as follows:

[image]

Could it be that the VPN adapter is using a different interface than ens0 and therefore I need to set the DisconnectLogout line in /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources to NO for that interface as well?

**Edit:** The wireless adapter still disconnects upon screen lock, so disregard my earlier claim. It worked fine when I slept it but when I used the screen lock alias, it didn't work. Not sure why this would be, so I'll need to look into this as well.

Comment: Have you [asked the developers of Viscosity](https://www.sparklabs.com/support/) directly? They are best placed to answer your question and provide support.

Comment: I haven't but will do so. Thank you for the advice!

Comment: Feel free to point the developer at this question, so they can provide an answer. Alternatively, you can add your own answer when they respond to help others.