# Why can't my laptop stay connected to WiFi when locked?

Tags: macos, wifi, screen-lock

My laptop isn't staying connected to it's wireless connection when I lock it. I set up an alias using [this post](http://osxdaily.com/2012/03/30/lock-mac-desktop-command-line/) and tried to follow the instructions from [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71884/wi-fi-disconnects-when-i-lock-the-mac), and those didn't work for me either. My prefs for en0 (the wireless interface) are as follows:

```
AirPort preferences for en0:

DisconnectOnLogout=NO
Unable to retrieve JoinMode
JoinModeFallback=DoNothing
RememberRecentNetworks=YES
RequireAdminIBSS=NO
RequireAdminNetworkChange=NO
RequireAdminPowerToggle=NO
WoWEnabled=YES
```

And the alias I use to lock the screen is:

```
alias lockscreen='/System/Library/CoreServices/"Menu Extras"/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend'
```

My system info is below as well:

[image: Laptop Details]

Any recommendations or any ideas of what I'm doing wrong? I don't believe this is a duplicate of the other question since the answers in there didn't work for me, so any advice would be appreciated.

**Edit:** Going to my username and clicking `Login Window...` to lock the screen also disconnects the WiFi.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing OS X El Capitan from your recovery partition?

Comment: No I haven't. I figured out an answer to it though so I'll post it.

Answer (score 1):

All right, so I've figured out a way to do it. I tried using the command `pmset displaysleepnow`, and it works as intended. The additional thing is that you have to go to System Preferences > Security & Privacy > General and require a password immediately after the computer display goes to sleep. I then set up an alias:

```
alias lscreen='pmset displaysleepnow'
```

and it works as intended. I use the terminal a lot, so lscreen is an easy way for me to lock my screen and come back with my screen being locked but both my WiFi and VPN still connected.